# Can't define my site on full width- bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap grid system, 
While I'm scrolling to the right side of the window  a white space appears:
[image]

I defined the body on width: 100vw;

How can I remove this space?

Comment: Add your code (make a working snippet) so we can help you quicker. Right now we are just doing guess work instead of actually fixing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though we don't have any of your code, I can make a small guess. I had this problem before and this seemed to fix my problem. Try it out.

```
html,body
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @r.i.r I struggled with this aswell! Good thing it worked :-) Happy coding